# HTML5 History Mode from vuerouter not work in production

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, vuejs2, vue-router

On my Laravel and Vue.js V2 project, I've implemented Vue Router v3 with History mode. It works perfectly on my development machine. However, as soon as I switch to production, I get the error message '**The requested URL was not found on this server.**'

I followed the official documentation (https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations), but there was no improvement.

My .htaccess in laravel

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    </IfModule>

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and my /etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName prod.mycompany.net
        ServerAlias laravel
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel/public

        <Directory "/var/www/html/laravel">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        LogLevel debug
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

and my apache's version

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2023-03-08T17:32:54
```

Does anyone know where the problem might be coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the error. It's come from .htaccess.

The good .htaccess who work :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
   
    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove that index.html handling in your .htaccess file (does it exist in /var/www/html/laravel/public?) and let Laravel routing point to the controller that will serve your Vue.js app.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put in your routes files (web.php) a fallback route ?

```php
Route::fallback(function() {
    return view('index');
});
```

Replace index with your actual blade startpoint for your Vue app.